# how to increase text label size using rectangle in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, rectangles

i want to increase label size using rectangular bound like it show in this picture. [image]

can any one tell me how to do this. thanks in advance.

Comment: What can I say? Make sure the label and the rectangle image has the same frame when you resize the label.

Comment: is there any snippet for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subclassing textview fixed it.